# Fourier transform of $f(x) = \frac {1}{4\pi x^2 + k^2}$ in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

I got a function $f(x) = \frac {1}{4\pi x^2 + k^2}$, where $k \gt 0$ is a constant.  And I wanted do make the fourier transform in $\Bbb R^3$ (it is solved in my textbook). But in the solution it was said that the transform is in the sense of the distributions. But why? Why this function isn't Lebesgue integrable, in $L^1(\Bbb R^3)$?

I understand that $\frac {1}{x^2}$ isn't in $L^1$, because the function isn't continuous in $x=0$. Even though $\frac {1}{x^2}$ goes to zero for $x \to \infty$. But I don't see any discontinuity in $\frac {1}{4\pi x^2 + k^2}$. So why it is needed to use the radial distribution. Because of the dimension? I am confused.

Comment: Is $x$ a radial coordinate of a spherically symmetric function, or is $x$ just the normal cartesian $x$ coordinate?

Comment: For a 3-D Fourier Transform of a function with radial symmetry, you may want to look at this answer to a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029986/441161

Comment: Thank you. Fun Fact: the similar question was posted by my classmate.