# Fourier transform of magnitude of a vector

Tags: fourier-transform

How would you do the Fourier transform of the magnitude of $v$ vector(i.e. $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ where $x,y,z$ are the components of the vector $v$)?

Is it similar to the one dimensional case? I haven’t been able to extrapolate the logic from the 1d case to the general vector.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When writing equations it's a good idea to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to make things look nicer.

Comment: Use the 3D Fourier Transform in spherical coordinates.  See this answer for the 3D FT when radial symmetry exists: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029986/441161

Comment: Thank you both very much! I will get familiar with MathJax.